# How to get the key's value and finish my delegate

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uipickerview

I'm a beginner so I apologize if this all looks very hacky.

I have a dictionary of Times and Time Amounts In Seconds. This is a countdown timer app with a `pickerView` that lets you pick the countdown time start and once you pick a time in pickerView's `didSelect`, it updates the timerLabel with that time amount. Then when you tap play, it plays down from that time amount.

I am trying to use a protocol in pickerView's `didSelect` to tell me when a time has been selected, then match the time to its value of Time amount in seconds, convert Seconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds and pass that info to the timer so that it can play down from that time. However, i'm getting stuck with finishing the delegate.

I'm getting this error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Int]' with an index of type '[String]' when I try to call for the value of the key in the protocol stub. I understand that basically I have an array and I can't get the key's value from it but I need help figuring out how to go backwards now... from array back to keys and values. I put all of Times in an array for pickerView but I'm getting stuck with how to get the value for the key selected in the array of Times I gave to pickerview.

Here is my code so far with where the error shows:

```
import UIKit

class TimerVC: UIViewController, TimerValueInSecondsDelegate {

struct Time {
    let name : String
    let amount : Double
}

let selectedTimes = [Time(name:"3 MIN", amount:180.0),
                     Time(name:"5 MIN", amount:300.0),
                     Time(name:"10 MIN", amount:600.0),
                     Time(name:"15 MIN", amount:900.0)]

var delegate: TimerValueInSecondsDelegate?
var counter = 1 //Starting value of seconds
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false //Make sure only one timer is created at a time.
let customWidth: CGFloat = 120
let customHeight: CGFloat = 60

@IBOutlet weak var timePickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var startTimerButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timerNumbers: UILabel! //Countdown label
@IBOutlet weak var cancelTimer: UIButton! //Cancel the timer

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timePickerView.dataSource = self
    timePickerView.delegate = self

    cancelTimer.isHidden = true
    timerNumbers.isHidden = true

    startTimerButton.setImage(UIImage(named : "startTimerButton"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    startTimerButton.setImage(UIImage(named : "pauseTimerButton"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    startTimerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startTimerAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(startTimerButton)
}

   func getSecondsValue(from time : Time) {
   let timeAmountValue = time.amount
}

@IBAction func startTimerAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if startTimerButton.isSelected == true {
        startTimerButton.isSelected = false
        timer.invalidate()
    }else {
        startTimerButton.isSelected = true
        runTimer()
    }

    cancelTimer.isHidden = false
    timerNumbers.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func cancelTimerAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer.invalidate()
    cancelTimer.isHidden = true
    timerNumbers.isHidden = true
    timerNumbers.text = String(counter)
    counter = 0
    startTimerButton.isSelected = false
    isTimerRunning = false
}

func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    isTimerRunning = true
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    counter -= 1
    //timerNumbers.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(counter))
}

func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let hours = Int(time) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}

extension TimerVC: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
//!! pickerView code below !!//
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    pickerView.subviews.forEach({
        $0.isHidden = $0.frame.height < 1.0
    })
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return selectedTimes.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let time = selectedTimes[row]
delegate?.getSecondsValue(from: time)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return customHeight
}

//custom pickerView label
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customWidth, height: customHeight))

    let pickerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customWidth, height: 50))
    pickerLabel.text = selectedTimes[row].name
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(pickerLabel)
    return view
}
}

protocol TimerValueInSecondsDelegate {
func getSecondsValue(from time : Time)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can just use `selectedTimes.values` if want to get all values? You are trying to subscript a dictionary with an array, its not going to work, you can only subscript it with a key value, in your case it should be a string

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the item from the array with the `row` index

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let time = timePickerArray[row]
    delegate?.getSecondsValue(from: time)
}
```

and declare `getSecondsValue`

```
func getSecondsValue(from time : String) {
  let timeInSeconds = selectedTimes[time] 
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Rather than a tuple use a struct

```
struct Time {
   let name : String
   let amount : Double
}

...

let selectedTimes = [Time(name:"3 MIN", amount:180.0), 
                     Time(name:"5 MIN", amount:300.0), 
                     Time(name:"10 MIN", amount:600.0), 
                     Time(name:"15 MIN", amount:900.0)]

...

func getSecondsValue(from time : Time) {
   let timeAmountValue = time.amount
}

...

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let time = selectedTimes[row]
    delegate?.getSecondsValue(from: time)
}

...

pickerLabel.text = selectedTimes[row].name
```

Comment: Thank you. I took my array out and tried to use the dictionary directly with selectedTimes[row].timeName instead of timePickerArray. I have updated my code with my change and your suggestion. Now I get an error that says "Cannot subscript a value of type '[(timeName: String, timeAmount: Double)]' with an index of type 'String' ". I added this error in the code above to show where it is. I still can't seem to match  the values (timeAmount) with the key from didSelect

Comment: Thank you. This is a dumb ? but I keep the protocol TimerValueInSecondsDelegate { func getSecondsValue(from: time) } in place, right? I changed the tuple to a struct and am getting this error at the protocol - "Use of undeclared type 'time'".

Comment: In the protocol declaration you have to change the signature, too: `func getSecondsValue(from time : Time)` and declare the struct outside of the class.

Comment: Thank you. I updated it to func getSecondsValue(from time : Time). The protocol is already sitting outside the class and extension, but the error shows "Use of undeclared type 'Time'". Is this because it can't observe the Time struct in the class?

Comment: The struct must be declared outside the class or you have to write `TimerVC.Time`

Comment: Thank you very much for walking me through this patiently. I will reference this again.

Comment: Please don't update the code in the question with the solution. The question makes no sense anymore and confuses other readers.